Angular 19: SSR + Lazyloading - Are there any resources?
I have recently upgraded my v17 production app to v19 for partial SSR.
The upgrade went well. The good:
Angular added ssr and updated the angular.json and needed server files

I added routes to the server routes and set them to server rendering.

I refactored all the instances of "location", "window" and whatever else.

The build process is error-free and serving with the server.ts

The app runs great when served this way, no regression

SSR is complete and I checked with the angular dev tools, its "working".
The bad:

Only the app.component is Serverside rendered. All other components are still then client rendered


I think the issue is due to lazy loading. It's a large production app, and everything is lazy-loaded.
I'll include some relevant files below if you want to help, but my real ask is this: Are there any helpful resources that get into the details of how to setup Lazyloading and SSR in angular19?
I have found a LOT of resources that basically say "Yah, you should do it, its hard". Or like 2 lines on "Don't forget to make changes in your main.server.ts for your lazy routes". But none that actually outline what changes I am supposed to make.
Here are some of the relevant files in case I am supposed to make just one little change.
app.routes.server.ts
import { RenderMode, ServerRoute } from '@angular/ssr';

export const serverRoutes: ServerRoute[] = [
    { 
        path: 'only/path/needed/ssr',
        renderMode: RenderMode.Server,
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        renderMode: RenderMode.Server
    }
];

server.ts
import { dirname, resolve } from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';

import {
  AngularNodeAppEngine,
  createNodeRequestHandler,
  isMainModule,
  writeResponseToNodeResponse,
} from '@angular/ssr/node';
import express from 'express';

const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');

const app = express();
const angularApp = new AngularNodeAppEngine();

/**
 * Example Express Rest API endpoints can be defined here.
 * Uncomment and define endpoints as necessary.
 *
 * Example:
 * 
 * app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => {
 *   // Handle API request
 * });
 * 
 */

/**
 * Serve static files from /browser
 */
app.use(
  express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    index: false,
    maxAge: '1y',
    redirect: false,
  }),
);

/**
 * Handle all other requests by rendering the Angular application.
 */
app.use('/**', (req, res, next) => {
  angularApp
    .handle(req)
    .then((response) =>
      response ? writeResponseToNodeResponse(response, res) : next(),
    )
    .catch(next);
});

/**
 * Start the server if this module is the main entry point.
 * The server listens on the port defined by the `PORT` environment variable, or defaults to 4000.
 */
if (isMainModule(import.meta.url)) {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

/**
 * The request handler used by the Angular CLI (dev-server and during build).
 */
export const reqHandler = createNodeRequestHandler(app);

app.module.server.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { provideServerRoutesConfig } from '@angular/ssr';
import { AuthConfigService, AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { serverRoutes } from './app.routes.server';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [AppModule, ServerModule],

  providers: [provideServerRoutesConfig(serverRoutes),
    {
      provide: AuthService,
      useValue: {},
    },
    { provide: AuthConfigService, 
      useValue: {} as any },],
})
export class AppServerModule {}

main.server.ts
export { AppServerModule as default } from './app/app.module.server';


If your server doesn't render your components its because the app became stable before your app reached the point where it should have rendered your lazy loaded componetns.

Yes, so how do I tell it to keep going?  I want it to SSR further into my lazy-loaded routes

We would need a fully fledge repo to understand what's happening in your app. Lazy-loading is supposed to work.

The lazy-loading works like a charm.  No complaints there.  I want the SSR to load the full route, which in theory shouldn't matter if it's lazy-loaded or not.  But technically I think it does.  I think I am just missing a step or two of configuration.

Really, if there are any sources that outline the steps of configuring lazy-loaded routes to work with SSR, that would be great.  I don't need someone to do all the work for me.

Here’s what I suspect:
In my opinion, this happens because hydration is not occurring properly. That’s why the related components are rendered using CSR. You’ll likely need to make some adjustments. it is not about lazy loading.
Why do I think this?

When I converted a CSR project to SSR, I had no issues with lazy-loaded routes. I did not touch the any app route config.
The Angular Hybrid Rendering guide doesn’t mention eager or lazy-loaded routes as a specific issue.

What you should check:

https://angular.dev/guide/hydration
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-coding-guidelines/
Just create a dummy lazy-loaded route and component in your project and check if it’s being server-side rendered.

If it is SSR, then the issue is related to hydration at the component level for the other components.
If it is not SSR, then it’s likely an app-wide issue, possibly with a service that works only on CSR. For instance, you might be using a platform check like isPlatformBrowser in the related app-wide services and using that service in app-component OnInit lifecycle etc.

I'll look at those resources and try creating a dummy route today.  Something you said was interesting.  I AM using isPlatformBrowser  in both the app.component and the parent class of all my services.  I do so to mock away the use of localStorage and window when its doing the SSR.  I thought this was the way to ensure that SSR would work, not that it would stop it here.

"Only the app.component is Serverside rendered. All other components are still then client rendered".
How do you know that all the other components are client rendered ?
Open the source code of the page you want to test using Google Chrome. Not "inspect", but show "source code". If the <app-root></app-root> is empty, then the current page is generated at client side. But if the <app-root></app-root> contains other elements, the current page is generated at server side, so you don't need to do anything else.
I know it can be confusing if you expect the whole page to load and your browser's loader to spin like it does with PHP, but it works differently with Angular.

Yes, that is how I know it is rendered client side.  Just to be sure I also checked the Angular dev tools in Chrome AND I used the platform service to render some text if it was client side or server side.
